# Can I create a new aspx file when submitting a form?

Tags: asp.net

My company currently conducts several webinars per month and we direct people to the webinar by sending them to a default page on the website which then forwards to the page that is set up for that days webinar. This means manually creating the page and then changing the redirect on the default page. I want to create an application that allows someone in our CS department to select from a list of upcoming webinars. The information from the database is written to another page where the webinar information is collected (password, URL and page name, and upload materials for the attendee to download). When submitting that I want to create the page that is redirected to (i.e. webinar_11514.aspx).

How do I create an entirely new file on submitting the form and post all of the information from the form to that page?

Comment: Are you sure this is a good design? Seems like a recipe for disaster. Why not just have a generic webinar.aspx page that displays differently according to the selected webinar passed via query string? Ex: `~/webinar.aspx?id=11514`? You might also investigate [FriendlyURL's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx) or using MVC.

Comment: Do you really need to hard-create a page that by design is intended to display dynamic content? Your scenario sounds like either a data driven web application or a case for a content management system.

Comment: it's good show what you have tried and what is your thought process

Comment: The reason is they want the webinar pages created and ready days and sometimes weeks in advance but only the next one should be available to the public via the redirect. We do not have a CMS on this site right now and are months away from that. I was just hoping there was a way to do this in the meantime.

Comment: @user1596194 But none of those reasons actually point to the need for creating separate pages for each webinar. Look at my first comment. It's using a single page to display whatever webinar is represented by the passed in ID. You can easily have a check (run an if statement on Page_Load) that determines if the webinar is the current "next" one.

Comment: Okay - I will give it a try. Thanks. As you can tell I am a beginner.

Comment: There are a few open-source solutions for URL aliasing (changing page.aspx?id=1234 to my-friendly-url). You may want to Google it so you can have friendlier URLs to give out.

Comment: The only problem with that is not all of the information needed for the webinar page is in the query. The user is going to have to upload the materials file as well as include the Webex URL.

Comment: @user1596194 Your database should store that data when you upload it. Then your webinar page should retrieve the data based on the ID passed via query string.

Comment: I don't want to save the URL/materials file/password for the webinar in the database. The database is part of our association management software. I don't want to add any columns to the tables or create any new tables to accommodate the additional information that is added. I just want to write it to the page and upload the materials file to the web server.

Comment: this is totally Genuine!

Comment: @user1596194 Please use the @ symbol to reply to a specific user. Otherwise no one may notice you've replied! And *still*, you haven't demonstrated a valid need to creating new `.aspx` files for each webinar. You need to use a database. It doesn't have to be the existing database, and it doesn't have to be a relational database. Some options are: XML files, JSON files, SQL Server Express. Please look at my answer I posted, as I'm 100% sure that it's going to result in a better and more secure approach than creating a separate `.aspx` file for each webinar.

Comment: @Mason - thanks again for your response. I don't doubt for a second that you are correct. I was just hoping there was another way. I will see what I can do.

Comment: @user1596194 There is another way. You *could* create a separate `.aspx` for each webinar. It'd just be a matter of using `File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("webinar_11514.aspx"),"some html")` and having the correct permissions. But it'd be a poor design. An awful design. If I was your boss, I'd consider removing you from my team if you did that. And it'd be hard to extract the data about each webinar from if you wanted to use elsewhere. And it'd be highly insecure.

Comment: @mason haha! - thanks for the warning. I will look into your original solution some more and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, a CMS is coming but you're still in the decision phase. You need something now that'll hold you over until the CMS is in place.

I'd use a few masterpages and lock your users into templated pages. It's going to happen when the CMS is in place, you may as well prepare them for it now. You can use something like XML in a database to set this type of page up and make it customizable. The content would be variable, but things like forms and button functionality should probably be consistent across all the pages. (You'll need to figure out what's constant vs variable)

If you're in an environment where a lot of things look different, you're going to have to lock that down. Once the CMS comes in, your templates become the options. Period. (Unless the page is created outside the CMS, which can and does happen)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, your **data** is separate from your **UI** and **application logic**.

An ASPX page is your UI. It controls how you view your data. The ASPX files themselves should *not* be changed in response to data. They should be static.

Instead of creating pages like `webinar_11514.aspx` for each webinar (during runtime), you should simply create a single `webinar.aspx` page (at design time). You can tell it which webinar to display by passing in query string parameters, example: `webinar.aspx?id=11414`. Your `Page_Load` function will retrieve that information and decide how to handle it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check to see if an ID was provided
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))         
    {
    //redirect the user to a page where they can select the webinar, or to an error page, or the home page
    }
    string id = Request.QueryString["id"]; //This will get the 11514 id from the URL.
    var webinar = Webinar.LoadById(id); //load the details of the webinar from a database. It doesn't have to be a relational database, it could be XML or JSON files stored in your ~/App_Data folder. You'll probably want to verify that the webinar for the given ID exists before actually pulling it
    if(!webinar.IsCurrent)
    {
    //tell the user the specified webinar is closed, perhaps redirect to an error page
    }

    //Begin loading UI elements with the details of the webinar
    WebinarTitleLbl.Text = webinar.Title; 
    WebExHyperLink.NavigateUrl = webinar.WebExUrl;
}
```

If you use the [FriendlyURL's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx) package, you can make the URL even cleaner. Instead of using `webinar.aspx?id=11514` you could use `webinar/11514`. Instead of using Query String, you'd use the Segments property made available via Friendly URL's. It's a lot easier to tell someone to go to `mysite.com/webinar/11514` than it is `mysite.com/webinar.aspx?id=11514`. It's also better for search engines.